# Normal Distribution Statistics

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am trying to understand normal distribution, and I am trying to get

> Verbal SAT scores following the normal (430, 100) distribution. What is the middle range of scores encompassing 50% of the population?

My attempt :

Since X~normal(430,100) denote SAT score, we want
y such that $P(\frac{430-y-430}{10} \le Z \le \frac{430+y-430}{10}) = 0.5$

Then 430's cancel out and we have $P(\frac{-y}{10} \le Z \le \frac{y}{10}) = 0.5$

Then I am confused as to what y values to choose in order to get 0.5.
Stats tables are not helping me because I am unsure of which value I am looking for. Can someone lend me a hand?

Comment: variance is 100 and sd is 10.

Comment: I am confused as to how to choose a range of y values such that probability is 0.5. Textbook is not helpful because it says "from the stats table we know the result is this."

Comment: Like Element118, I suspect the SD might be $100$, since $10$ feels awfully small.  In the standard normal table (reverse lookup) it seems that $\Pr(Z\le 0.675)\approx 0.75$, so we get about $0.25$ in the right tail. So $y$ is about $0.675$ times the SD.

Comment: Because $Z$ is symmetric, $P(-a<Z<a)=1-2P(Z\le -a)$ and the latter you can find in a table. Also, 100 must be std, not variance. STD of 10 is way too small to ever reach even 530.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How did you come up with $(Z \le 0.675)$ ? I am asking because the correct answer is y = 6.75. How did you conclude that?

Comment: I looked in the **body** of the standard normal table for the number $0.75$. Did not find it exactly, at $0.67$ we get under, at $0,68$ we get over by about the same amount. By interpolation $0.675$ is about right. There is also software that will do it, to higher accuracy, but high accuracy is pointless here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I think I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first statement is incorrect, leading to confusion
right from the start.

In terms of $Y \sim Norm(\mu=430, \sigma=10),$ you want to find $b$
such that that $P(Y < b) = .75.$ Then standardize to
express the question in terms of standard normal $Z \sim Norm(0,1).$

$$P\left\{Z = \frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{b - 430}{100} \right\} = .75.$$
Then, looking at normal tables you can see that $(b-430)/100 \approx 0.6745,$ which you can solve for $b$. In a similar way, you can find the lower
endpoint $a$ of the interval that contains the 'middle half' of the
exam scores.

I understand that this is only an outline of the method, but I hope
you can take it from there--perhaps by taking excellent Comments
into account.

From R software, these values can be obtained without
standardizing, and in one statement, as shown below.
The answers are not exactly the same because using the software is
slightly more accurate than using printed tables. Because
exam scores are integers, you probably want to give integer
answers.

```
qnorm(c(.25, .75), 430, 10)
423.255102498039 436.744897501961
```

It is usually helpful to draw a sketch in solving such problems. The three vertical lines in the figure below break the density
curve for $Norm(430,100)$ into four areas, each of 0.25 probability.

[image]